# Service Fabric SDK Log Size

Tags: visual-studio, azure, visual-studio-2015, azure-service-fabric

Is it possible to reduce the logsize on Local VS2015 development instances of the service fabric SDK?

It seems to generate 120M trace files every 40 minutes. I installed the SDK yesterday and its already generated 6G worth of trace and log files.

Is there a way to restrict this or get it to write over old logs?

Answer (score 0):

Stop the data collectors.
Or while installing new cluster (in cluster manifest) you can specify LogLevel (by default it's 4).